# "Version of the items" or "versions of the items"?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Example sentence:

> I navigated through the shelves, matching their numbers with the ones
>   in my information tags, which would lead me to the flattened
>   **version(s)** of the furnishings I fell in love with.

Do I need the *s*? Why or why not?

Note: I only found one instance of the first: "a digitally flattened version of the hummed sentences." [Source](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwji1pznr47XAhWGVLwKHaVdCAAQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fludwig.guru%2Fs%2Fflattened%2Bversion&usg=AOvVaw095wStZ7tVEVMMhuXVQcxD). Not sure if it's correct, though.

Comment: It could be either. It depends on how many versions you expect to find. Keep in mind that, in your example itself, you don't the results yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need the S - unless all items have the same version.

If not, then there are multiple items, each with one of more versions, so you need to speak of versions.

If each item has only one version, then consider

> which would lead me to the flattened version of each of the furnishings I fell in love with

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why would you write *that I fell in love with* instead of *I fell in love with*?

Comment: -1: There is nothing wrong with eliminating ***that*** in the sentence. Such elisions are common and well understood. And they're actually how people talk most of the time. There is no semantic difference between the two versions.

Comment: Ok, I can accept that. Just a knee jerk feeling when I saw it written. Hmmm, a meta question might be whether this site address written or spoken English and whether we should state which in questions.  I just wish that I had added it as a comment, to avoid your downvote :-(

Comment: I have editted the answer to remove that contention

Comment: Downvote removed.